# HP Spectre X360-15t (2018) overheats on idle with Linux Mint 19.3 and fans do not start

Tags: linux, linux-mint, fan

I am a new Linux Mint user currently using version 19.3 with Cinnamon Desktop (installed with MATE but switched). I have observed that my laptop has been running very hot even on tasks like browsing and video streaming  and the fans don't start up even on high temperatures. Switching over to windows after using Linux starts the fan at full speed immediately so it does not seem to be a hardware issue. I have tried using `tlp` and `thermald` but things don't seem to have improved. Also I am concerned about the heat permanently damaging my laptop. Here is an output from sensors which shows the output of sensors showing that high threshold is at 100:

```
:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Same goes for me, the fan starts kicking in at around 94 °C and then keeps spinning until it reaches 54 °C.

System is updated to the latest kernel (5.3.0-46) and I am dual booting with windows, where the fan works fine (starting at around 65-70 °C).
Bios is updated to the latest version.

Is there a system component that controls the fan or is it just the bios? I suppose it's the OS, otherwise I cannot understand why it would work in windows and not in Mint.

Thanks